# Swift Change look of Uitabcontroller?

Tags: swift, uitabcontroller

Recently tried to implement a toolbar in my app, for now I'm using the uitabcontroller which is built in.

I wondered if it was possible to edit something like so: 
http://i64.tinypic.com/iwlxzo.jpg

I've failed to find any documentation on customising a uitabcontroller or creating one...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to subclass UITabbarController to perform the changes that you require. I suggest you look up subclassing to get the right idea.